# R shiny map marker click event

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I have a shiny leaflet map which draw markers while input$map_marker_click is null, when I click these markers, another dataset which is past route of my  previous dataset is used as an input to show different markers. After showing past route, I go back to my first dataset with pressing button to change input$map_marker_click as null. However, I cannot again show past route of my data. Can you help me? My ui code :

**ui**

column(10,actionButton("remove", "Remove"),
tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetValue', function(variableName) {
Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
Shiny.setInputValue(variableName, null);
});"))

**server**

observe({

```
temp =Data()
temp2 = historyData()
event <-input$mapH_marker_click
if(nrow(temp)!=0){
  
  if(!is.null(event)){
    leafletProxy("mapH")%>%
      clearMarkerClusters() %>%
      leaflet.extras::clearHeatmap()%>%
      addMarkers(data=temp2,icon = shipicon,label =sprintf("<br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Time:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Name:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Longitude:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Latitude:</font> %s <br/>",temp2$TIME,temp2$SHIPNAME,temp2$LAT,temp2$LON)
                 %>%lapply(htmltools::HTML),clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
    
  }
  else if(is.null(event)){
    leafletProxy("mapH")%>%
      clearMarkerClusters() %>%
      leaflet.extras::clearHeatmap()%>%
      
      addMarkers(data=temp,icon = shipicon,label =sprintf("<br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Time:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Name:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Longitude:</font> %s <br/><font size=2 color=#045FB4> Latitude:</font> %s <br/>",temp$TIME,temp$SHIPNAME,temp$LAT,temp$LON)
                 %>%lapply(htmltools::HTML),clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
  }
  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "mapH_marker_click")
  })
  
}
```

})

Comment: I solved problem

Comment: can you post your answer to help future readers? Thanks